# Python - Create multiple folders from an excel column list

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am basically trying to get Python to create a bunch of folders in a directory with each folders name based on a list in an Excel file. The list is in column D, that has a heading "Folder Name".

I have been able to do this with an individual cell, but struggling to figure out how to do it for multiple. The code I have so far is below.

Your help is really appreciated - I am very new to this!`

```
import os
import openpyxl


def folder_creation(EXCEL_FILE_DIRECTORY, FOLDER_CREATION_LOCATION, EXCEL_FILE_NAME):
   os.chdir (EXCEL_FILE_DIRECTORY)
   workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook (EXCEL_FILE_NAME)
   sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name ('Sheet1')
   folderName = sheet ['D2'].value
   baseDir = FOLDER_CREATION_LOCATION 
   os.makedirs(os.path.join(baseDir, folderName))
   print ("\nFolder created in: ", os.path.join(baseDir, folderName))
```

Comment: Are you open to using `pandas`? You may find more people familiar with `pandas` syntax vs `openpyxl`..

Comment: I am open to it - definitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through all column values. This works for me (openpyxl v2.5):

```
def folder_creation(EXCEL_FILE_DIRECTORY, FOLDER_CREATION_LOCATION,  EXCEL_FILE_NAME):
    os.chdir(EXCEL_FILE_DIRECTORY)
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(EXCEL_FILE_NAME)
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

    col_values = [cell.value for col in sheet.iter_cols(
        min_row=2, max_row=None, min_col=4, max_col=4) for cell in col]

    for value in col_values:       
        folderName = value
        baseDir = FOLDER_CREATION_LOCATION
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(baseDir, folderName))
        print("\nFolder created in: ", os.path.join(baseDir, folderName))
```

Comment: Ok will try this now. Will report back. Thanks

Comment: This worked also, and it cut out the header, which is even better. I still get the error message at the end: TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Did I get the error because it is getting to the end of the column, realising it is blank and failing? FYI - It created my folders then popped up the error.

Comment: The only error I'm getting is that you're using a deprecated openpyxl command: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname])

Comment: Maybe add a try/except block around the for loop that makes the folders (to trap the TypeError )?

Comment: You may have an empty cell that's getting read but evaluates to None...try adding a new value to the next row in column D or make a new test sheet.

Comment: Added a new value to next row and it seemed to help - no more errors. Strange... Thanks so much for your help though Russ! You obv know your stuff!

Answer (score 0):

A for loop?

```
import os
import openpyxl


def folder_creation(EXCEL_FILE_DIRECTORY, FOLDER_CREATION_LOCATION, EXCEL_FILE_NAME):
   os.chdir (EXCEL_FILE_DIRECTORY)
   workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook (EXCEL_FILE_NAME)
   sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name ('Sheet1')
   baseDir = FOLDER_CREATION_LOCATION 
   col = sheet['D']

   for cell in col:
        folderName = cell.value
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(baseDir, folderName))
        print ("\nFolder created in: ", os.path.join(baseDir, folderName))
```

Comment: **So**, this actually worked and created the folders, but it came back with an error: TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Is this because it is getting to the end of the column, realising it is blank and failing? FYI - It created my folders **then** popped up the error.