# Create folders and download images from url in excel in Python

Tags: python, pandas

How can I download images from `url` in `df` to two folders `dog` and `cat`, if their values in `dog` and `cat` columns are equal to `1.0`?

Thank you!

```
   id                                                url  dog   cat
0   1  https://c-ssl.duitang.com/uploads/item/201405/...   1.0  1.0
1   2  https://c-ssl.duitang.com/uploads/item/201407/...   NaN  1.0
2   3  https://timgsa.baidu.com/timg?image&quality=80...   1.0  NaN
```

My code so far for reference only if it's necessary:

```
src = input("Path of df：").replace("'", "")
def download_pic(df):
    global progress_num
    dst = join(os.path.split(src)[0], folder_name)
    try:
        os.mkdir(dst)
    except:
        pass

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        url = row['url']
        file_name = os.path.basename(urlparse(url).path)
        try:
            r = requests.get(url, timeout=(5, 10))
        except:
            try:
                r = requests.get(url, timeout=(5, 10))
            except:
                try:
                    r = requests.get(url, timeout=(5, 10))
                except:
                    progress_num += 1
                    with open("fail_url.txt", "a") as f:
                        f.write(url + "\n")
                    continue


        filepath = join(dst, str(row['id'])).replace("nan", "")
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(filepath):
                os.makedirs(filepath)
        except:
            pass

        filepath = join(filepath, file_name)

        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(filepath, "wb") as f:
                f.write(r.content)
        else:
            print(url)
            print(r.status_code)

        progress_num += 1
```

Comment: Use a `while True` loop for your `requests`, instead of nested `try-except` clauses.

Comment: what is a problem ? It seems you have all code to do this. Do you get error message or what ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: It did't create folders `cat` and `dog`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334591/python-create-multiple-folders-from-an-excel-column-list